# Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when posting list of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm trying to post the list of users `@shop.users`, which is all the users that belong_to a Shop.

The error `Undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` Occurs when I try to render this partial

```
<div class="hero-unit user_info">
  <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
</div>
```

I imagine it's because @user isn't defined/iterated through properly to show each user.  I need help doing that properly.

Here is the customers method in ShopsController

```
def customers
  @shop = Shop.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @customers = @shop.users
end
```

Here is the page /customers

```
<div id="customers_feed">
    <% if @customers.any? %>
      <ul class="customers">
        <%= render @customers %>
      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <h3> No customers have added you as their designated shop yet.</h3>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Where `render @customers` starts the partial I showed above with @user.name getting the error.

I'm not sure how to properly define `user` so that each user's name who belonging to the shop is rendered properly.  How can I make this work?

Comment: Who is the user in your app? Is user and customer the same?

Comment: The Users are Customers, but Customers are specifically the Users that belong to a specific Shop

Comment: Ok, since you've already assigned the those 'users' to the @customer instance variable in your controller, you just need to iterate over them in your partial. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a partial `_customer` and change your code like this

```
<div class="hero-unit user_info">
  <h1><%= customer.name %></h1>
</div>
```

replace this

```
<%= render @customers %>
```

to

```
<%= render 'customer', collection: @customers, as: :customer %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your partial to:

```
<div class="hero-unit user_info">
    <% customers.each do |customer| %>
  <h1><%= customer.name %></h1>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

And your customers template to:

```
<div id="customers_feed">
    <% if @customers.any? %>
      <ul class="customers">
        <%= render partial "customers", locals: { customers: @customers } %>
      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <h3> No customers have added you as their designated shop yet.</h3>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection rendering in partials doesn't not use instance variables, you need to drop the `@user` and use `user`:

```
<div class="hero-unit user_info">
  <h1><%= user.name %></h1>
</div>
```